# Set scroll position to the top for hidden element reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, scroll

I'm using reactjs for my project and currently face a problem here.

I have a typical webpage with a side menu that will toggle hidden/visible when pressing the burger icon on top. This side menu has a list of item and it is scrollable. The burger icon will move up and hidden from our view when we scroll the side menu to bottom. When I click an item on the side menu to go to a page, the side menu of course will disappeared/hidden. Problem is, the burger-icon get disappeared too.

I think the problem lies on the scroll position does not reset back to top when I click an item on the bottom of the side menu.

How do we reset the scroll position of side menu to top when it is hidden?
I have tried window.scrollto(0,0) but did not work because I think this is for the page at the back of my side menu.

Comment: Are you saying the side menu remains "scrolled down" when you click on an item? Some code would help : )

Comment: Would you share your code, it's hard to help without that?